# Auto fit width of li to text?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there anyway possible to auto fit the width of an <li> tag to the width of the text it contains using CSS?

I'm designing a website that uses a custom CMS (and I don't have access to the code), so I'm limited in options as far as design goes.

Javascript solutions that would work on an <li> tag without having to edit any of the list properties directly would work as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @willoller already said, the **li** element is a block level element, but apart from floating it, you can also use:

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: beware that inline is not fully functional in IE

Comment: This will cause all list items to display as text on the same line. If you want the list to remain formatted as a list, with each list item on its own line, apply `display:inline` to the `<ul>` instead: `ul { display: inline }`. This will shrink both the list and the list items to the width of the longest list item.

Answer (score 19):

The `<li>` is a block-level element, so defaults to be as wide as it can be.

To get it to "shrinkwrap" to the size of the contents, try floating it:

```
li {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

That may do what you are looking for.

If you want the `<li>`s to sit alongside each other you can try:

```
ul {
    clear: left;  /* I like to put the clear on the <ul> */
}
li {
    float: left;
}
```

OR

```
li {
    display: inline
}
```

Making it `inline` takes away its block-level status, so it acts like a `<span>` or any other inline element.

Comment: For `li { display: inline }` see my comment to the accepted answer. My solution also uses less code than all those floats and clears and avoids problems if you forgot to add clear to the *next* item below the list or have no cannot change that part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Unfortunatly the following solution is displayed differently in different browsers.

In order to not let any other element float aside the list I used this:

```
ul {
    white-space: pre-line;
    margin: -25px 0 0;   /* to compensate the pre-line down-shift */ 
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The only CSS solution that worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul { display: inline }
```

will solve all of your problems at once.

Answer (score 1):

On standard compliant browsers, use `min-width` instead of `width`. On IE 6, `width` does what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers work correctly for me, so I used the following approach:

1. Add the style "float: left" to my <ul>
2. Surround the <ul> in another <div>

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: inline;` CSS to the `<ul>` block has worked great for me, with no undesired effects.

Answer (score 0):

If have the id of the <li> tag you could use JavaScript to get how many characters there were and then multiply that by the font size, then set the li width to that number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use em's rather than pixels to specify the width of your element. An em is roughly equivalent to the width of the letter "m" in the default font. Play with multiples of the number of characters in your li until you have an em width that is visualy appealing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was float:right that fixed it for me:

[image]

[image]