# How can I make my background-color fill all my content, even with horizontal scrolling?

Tags: html, css, background-color, horizontal-scrolling, pre

I'm using an `<ol>` to show a code snippet with line numbers. Since I'm showing program code, I disable wrapping (and enable indentation) by setting `white-space: pre` on `li`, which means an `li`'s content can extend past the right margin and cause the page to have a horizontal scroll bar. So far so good.

The problem comes when I want to set background colors on some of the `li`s to call out particular lines of code. I can set `background-color` on the `li`, but the color only extends to the right margin of the page; in fact, the last 10 pixels or so of text (an amount equal to the body's right margin) has no background color. And if I scroll horizontally, it's even worse: the background color scrolls left off the page. The background-color is only one browser-width wide (minus the page margins).

[Here's a fiddle illustrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/tp6Um/). If you scroll right, I want the background to be blue for as far as there's text.

How can I get the `background-color` to fill the full width of the content, even if the page scrolls horizontally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "shrink-wrap" each `li`'s content with a combination of `float` and `clear`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341982/2231440).

```
li {
    white-space: pre;
    background: blue;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    min-width:100%;
}
```

The last line is from koala_dev's answer. It forces shorter-content elements to have full-width background.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tp6Um/3/)

Comment: This can also use the `min-width: 100%` from koala_dev's answer, so shorter items at least extend to the right margin.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `display: inline-block` to make each list item fit its content. Combine this with `min-width:100%;` to make shorter-content `li`s stretch to full container's width.

```
li {
    white-space: pre;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:100%;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tp6Um/1/)**

Comment: This removes the numbering though.

Comment: @Neikos You can use CSS counters to get back the line numbers ([see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tp6Um/5/)) but then it turns to a more complicated approach than what trojansdestroy suggested.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that. Learned something new :)

Comment: At some font sizes (e.g. Consolas 10pt, which I'm using), this leaves vertical gaps between each list item  ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UUdP/)). It happens in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10, and only when you add `display: inline-block`. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with using directly a `li` item.

But a simple `span` inside the `li` fixes this.

Here is the relevant code:

```
span {
    white-space: pre; 
}
.highlight {
    background: blue;
}
```

Your markup would be along the lines of:

```
<ol>
    <li><span> Code Here... </span></li>
    <li><span class="highlight"> Code Here... </span></li>
</ol>
```

The reason for this is. If you change the `li`'s display to anything else than list-item it will lose it's numbering. (In Chrome at least.) So this way you get both with just a bit more overhead.

A jsfiddle showcasing it: http://jsfiddle.net/tp6Um/4/

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to kind of fix your problem

```
li 
{
white-space:pre;
display:block;
width:150%;
}
```

set the percentage accordingly

Comment: This won't work for content of various lengths, and doesn't help for content of unknown length.

Comment: :\ Sorry just tried to give sort of an idea. Im trying to get rep

Comment: No need to apologize; I'm just trying to offer some transparency. As far as rep, you'll get there eventually. Editing posts to clarify questions is a good start, if you're patient.

Comment: I try my best to help with what I can and with the little that I know not limited of course because I sometimes search online for answers. Thank you though I appreciate it.